# In Lua, how should I read a file into an array of bytes?

Tags: file-io, lua

To read a file into an array of bytes `a`, I have been using the following code:

```
file = io.open(fileName, "rb")
str = file:read("*a")
a = {str:byte(1, #str)}
```

Although this works for smaller files, `str:byte` fails for a 1MB file, giving `stack overflow (string slice too long)`.

Is there an alternative method which will successfully read these larger files?

Comment: Why do you want the contents into an array of bytes? You can easily extract each byte from the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
local fileName = 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\excel.exe'
local file = assert(io.open(fileName, 'rb'))
local t = {}
repeat
   local str = file:read(4*1024)
   for c in (str or ''):gmatch'.' do
      t[#t+1] = c:byte()
   end
until not str
file:close()
print(#t)   --> 18330984
```

Comment: Why is it 4*1024?

Comment: @Coal - To be aligned with a disk sector and a memory page.

Answer (score 1):

In case of using LuaJIT, another approach is to read a chunk of bytes and convert it to a C array.  If reading the whole file in one shot, the buffer should allocate enough memory to store it (filesize bytes).  Alternativaly, it could possible to read the file in chunks and reuse the buffer for each chunk.

The advantage of using a C buffer is that it's more efficient, memory-wise, than to convert a chunk of bytes to a Lua string or to a Lua table. The disadvantage is that FFI is only supported in LuaJIT.

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

-- Helper function to calculate file size.
local function filesize (fd)
   local current = fd:seek()
   local size = fd:seek("end")
   fd:seek("set", current)
   return size
end

local filename = "example.bin"

-- Open file in binary mode.
local fd, err = io.open(filename, "rb")
if err then error(err) end

-- Get size of file and allocate a buffer for the whole file.
local size = filesize(fd)
local buffer = ffi.new("uint8_t[?]", size)

-- Read whole file and store it as a C buffer.
ffi.copy(buffer, fd:read(size), size)
fd:close()

-- Iterate through buffer to print out contents.
for i=0,size-1 do
   io.write(buffer[i], " ")
end
```

Answer (score -1):

This will store each `block` (1) bytes from the file `file.txt` into the table `bytes`

```
local bytes = {}
file = assert(io.open("file.txt","rb"))
block = 1 --blocks of 1 byte
while true do
    local byte = file:read(block)
    if byte == nil then
        break
    else
        bytes[#bytes+1] = string.byte(byte)
    end
end
file:close()
```